# Sonar issue: A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getDataSource()" can return null. How to solve in try with resources block

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, underscore-java

This are the code try with resources block.

```
try (Connection con = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                Statement statement = con.createStatement()) {
    
         ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is wrong on more then one level. You have a [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) and just use it as a carrier for the `DataSource` instead of using it properly.

Depending on what you want to do you should use one of the `query` or `execute` methods on the `JdbcTemplate` instead of obtaining the `DataSource` and getting the `Connection`.

If you really want the `Connection` use a `ConnectionCallback` with an `execute` method instead.

```java
jdbcTemplate.execute( (Connection con) -> {
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
  Statement statement = con.createStatement();
})
```

But as mentioned you probably should be using one of the `query` methods instead of doing what youa re doing now!.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer but wouldn't it be better to use:
`jdbcTemplate.execute(sql, (PreparedStatement statement) -> {
      ...
      return null;
});`

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do, maybe you need the connection to prepare something before creating a statement. Ideally you would only need `jdbcTemplate.query*` methods and/or the basis `jdbcTemplate.update` but the need might arise one needs/want to use the plain `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` etc. Stating which one is better and should always be used isn't possible because it all depends. One thing can be said, `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()` is always a bad thing!.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this:

```
   DataSource ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
   if (ds != null) {
       try (Connection con = ds.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            Statement statement = con.createStatement()) {

            ....
       }
   }
```

The thing is that a `DataSource` is not `AutoClosable`.  Therefore there is no need to manage it with the *try with resources*.

Furthermore, if the `DataSource` >is< `null`, you won't be able to get a connection or a statement, and there is probably nothing that you could sensibly in the try body if the statement was `null`.  An explicit `null` test will avoid all of that.

But if we take into account the way that `JdbcTemplate` is designed to be used, I think that @M.Deinum's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73222864/139985) gives better ways to solve this.

Comment: While it might be better to use some callback I don't think this is a real issue and could be considered false positive.